# Dynamic get data in select box codeigniter

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have two select boxes, if I select an option, it will give me results according to the options and then the results will display in the 2nd select box. How can I do this?
I think, I have to do a `onchange` function but I don't know how can I get data from controller in JavaScript .

```
class StockInController extends MY_Controller {
    function index(){
        $data['main_content'] = 'stockInView';

        $this->load->model('supplierModel');
        $query = $this->supplierModel->getAllSuppliers();

        if ($query){
            $data['records1'] = $query; 
        } 

        $this->load->model('categoryModel');
        $query = $this->categoryModel->getAllCategories();

        if ($query){
            $data['records2'] = $query;
        }

        $this->load->model('itemsModel');
        $query = $this->itemsModel->getAllItems();

        if ($query){
            $data['records3'] = $query;

        }
        $this->load->view('dashboardTemplate/template',$data); 
    }

    function addStockIn(){
        //getting parameters from view 
        $data = array(
            'item_name' => $this->input->post('item_name'),
            'cat_id' => $this->input->post('cat_id')        
        );

        //$is_ajax = $this->input->post('ajax'); //or use this line
        //$this->input->is_ajax_request();

        $result = array();
        $this->load->model('stockInModel'); 
        $query = $this->stockInModel->addStocktoDB($data);

        if ($query){  //&& any other condition
            $result['res'] = 1;//process successful - replace 1 with any message
        } else {
            $result['res'] = 0;//process failed - replace 0 with any message
        }
        echo json_encode($result);//at the end of the function.
    }
}
```

Here is the View:

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label for="selsear" class="control-label">Select a Category</label>
    <div class="controls">
         <select name="select1" id="seslsear" class='cho'>
            <option id = "y" value="0">--Select--</option>
            <?php foreach($records2 as $r) { ?>
            <option value="<?=$r->cat_id?>"><?=$r->cat_name?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="control-group">
    <label for="selsear" class="control-label">Select an item</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <select name="select1" id="selsear" class='cho'>
            <option id = "y" value="0">--Select--</option>
            <?php foreach($records3 as $r) { ?>
            <option value="<?=$r->item_id?>"><?=$r->item_name?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: how do you want to load data by using javascript or jquery with ajax?

Comment: if i select a specific category .. it will show me all the item names against that category in 2nd select box.. i just want this functionality..

Answer (score -1):

You will have to write a function on-change of select box & feed data in success of ajax

```
$('#selsear').change(function() {

 var form_data = {
    item_name: $('#item_name').val(),
    cat_id: $('#selsear').val()
 };

$.ajax({
       url:'controller_name/function_name',
       data:form_data,    
       datatype:'application/json',
       success:function(data){
           $.each(data,function(i){
                          htmlString="<option value='"+data[i]['item_id']+"'>'"+data[i]['item_name']+"'</option>"
           });
           $("#selsear").html(htmlString);
       }
});
```

The controller function name is the name of function which retrieves data from controller.

I hope this will help you!

Comment: the url should be controller_name/function_name.

Comment: and no need to the comma after ca_id in the array for_data declaration

Comment: sorry @mamdouhalramadan  its a typo!

Comment: you specified that it's json, and you have to declare if it's POST or what. then you have to deal with data as json not regular array. like data.element not data[element]

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan  I did it before saying sorry! ,anyways tahnks for correcting

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan both (data.element & data[element]) will do the job!

Comment: I know :) I'm just trying to help :)